# Augment Yup locale definitions

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I'm trying to augment the Yup `DateLocale` ([source](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/locale.ts#L61)) to add locale support for the custom `compareToday` function I added. However, while the custom `compareToday` function **does** work, unfortunately all attempts to augment `DateLocale` in order to access it in Yup `setLocale` does not work. Strangely, augmentation of `LocaleObject` does add *new* keys but does not augment/merge *existing* keys.

```
// yup/types.ts
export type YupCompareTodayOp = "=" | "!=" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=";
```

```
// yup/locale.ts

// Adding custom function works with TS declarations!
addYupMethod(date, "compareToday", function method(op: YupCompareTodayOp, message?: string) {
  return this.test(
    "compareToday",
    message ?? "${path} fails comparison with today",
    function validate(value) {
      if (!value) return true;
      // TODO: Handle various date comparisons (ie. <, >, >=, <=, =, !=)
    },
  );
});

setYupLocale({
  date: {
    // TS error as 'compareToday' does not exist on type
    compareToday: ({ path }) => {
      key: "common:validations.date.compareToday",
      values: { path },
    },
    // Works as expected
    max: ({ max, path }) => {
      key: "common:validations.date.max",
      values: { path, max },
    },
  }
});
```

```
import { DateLocale, LocaleObject, Message, Yup } from "yup";
import { YupCompareTodayOp } from "#src/localization/yup/types";

declare module "yup" {
  // Overriding `DateSchema` works, and allows referencing `date().compareToday("eq")`
  interface DateSchema<
    TType extends Maybe<Date> = Date | undefined,
    TContext = AnyObject,
    TDefault = undefined,
    TFlags extends Flags = "",
  > {
    compareToday(op: YupCompareTodayOp, message?: string): this;
  }

  // Neither keys appear within `setLocale` under `date` key
  interface DateLocaleNew {
    dateLocale: string;
    compareToday?: Message<{ op: YupCompareTodayOp }>;
  }

  // Oddly, the `localeObject` key appears within `setLocale`, but the
  //   changes to `date` do not...
  interface LocaleObject {
    localeObject: string;
    date?: {
      localeObjectDate: string;
      compareToday?: Message<{ op: YupCompareTodayOp }>;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not necessary, as I found out after *hours* of attempting to debug/fix. As it turns out, since Yup extension methods can specify a custom error message in their `test` rule (see [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema)).

For example, I was *already* customizing the message of the `compareToday` test; in fact, this localization was what was being applied, **not** the localization in the `setLocale` call (which I thought was "working" but not recognized by TS)!

```
addYupMethod(date, "compareToday", function method(op: YupCompareTodayOp, message?: string) {
  return this.test(
    "compareToday",
    // Message can be a function, which can return localization helpers in the
    //   same way that default messages can be overridden with 'setLocale'!
    (args) => message ?? {
      key: "validations.date.compareToday",
      values: { path: args.path, context: op },
    },
    function validate(value) {
      if (!value) return true;
      // TODO: Handle various date comparisons (ie. <, >, >=, <=, =, !=)
    },
  );
});
```

TL;DR: There is no reason to override custom Yup extension methods because this is implicitly supported when defining the custom method's default message!